# A binomial expansion inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

Let us consider $x, y > 0$ then given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following inequality holds true
$$
(x+y)^\frac{1}{n} \leq x^\frac{1}{n} + y^\frac{1}{n}
$$
since
$$
((x+y)^\frac{1}{n})^n = x + y \leq (x^\frac{1}{n} + y^\frac{1}{n})^{n}  = x+ y +\text{some positive terms}.
$$
Now let us consider $x, y$ as above and let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ then does the following inequality holds true, and any suggestion to prove it?
$$
(x+ y)^\alpha \leq x^\alpha + y ^\alpha.
$$

Comment: Before going straight to real numbers, can you show the inequality holds for rational numbers in $(0,1)$? Once it holds for rational numbers, given any $\alpha \in (0,1)$, given any $\varepsilon>0$, you can find $\delta > 0$ such that $$\left|\dfrac{a}{b}-\alpha \right| < \delta \Longrightarrow \left|(x+y)^\alpha-(x+y)^{a/b}\right| < \varepsilon$$ You need to be a little careful here, but IIRC, this was a general outline of these types of proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(x+y)^\alpha-x^\alpha=\int_x^{x+y}\alpha t^{\alpha-1}\,dt\le \int_{x}^{x+y}\alpha (t-x)^{\alpha-1}\,dt=y^\alpha-\require{cancel}\cancel{0^\alpha}.
$$

Comment: I wish I was clever like that. (Although you could use some dt's on those integrals--smile).

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn To be fair, I remembered the solution from an analysis homework way back.

Comment: Thanks... it seems that I always find an analysis homework that I haven't done

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use Karamata here.

Indeed, let $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ and $x\geq y$.

Thus, $f$ is a concave function and $(x+y,0)\succ(x,y).$

Id est, by Kartamata
$$f(x+y)+f(0)\leq f(x)+f(y),$$ which is your inequality.